# Varnish SSL with Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, varnish

I have a website on my server and install Varnish , all right . Now I'm going to install the SSL certificates and I read that Varnish does not support SSL, I have to install Nginx to operate the certificates. Anyway , just be installing Nginx and my question is whether the SSL pages will have the benefit of the cache? Or the SSL pages, will not have cache.

Forgive me if my question is very simple, it is that I'm new at this and do not know much about web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up NGINX to take care of SSL termination. If you do so, you still have caching for SSL. Take a look at SSL termination [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04) for more detail.